# Show popup/window in a gwt tab

Tags: gwt, tabs, popup, panel

Is it possible to show a popup only in a certain gwt tab or a panel in that tab?
I've found methods to show a popups over the whole page, but not only in specific tabs.
When you switch the gwt tab, the popup should not be visible anymore and new popups should be able to be created, which again are only visible in the switched to gwt tab. Switching back to the other tab should then show the first popup again.

Optionally the rest of the tab, which is not covered by the popup, should not be clickable.

Are there any native methods for this? The gwt Popup Panel only seems to create popups for the whole page.

Edit: I've tried using smartgwts Window which seems to work just the way I want it to. When I switch the gwt-tab, the popup is no longer visible and returns when I switch back. The only problem is, that it isn't displayed right. The frame is placed on the far left side of the browser tab, while the content is displayed on the far left of the gwt-tab. If I move the content, the frame moves too. The frame is visible over the whole browser tab, while the content disappears if I drag it over the gwt-tab edge.
I guess it's because I'm adding a Window to a gwt-Panel. Is there any way to fix this without changing everything to smartgwt?

Comment: I was thinking about this too

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, I think.

But, you can do something in the tab events, like hide the popup in tabs that it doesnt belongs. To avoid the lag of show/hide the popup, you can do this in the BeforeSelectionHandler, like this:

```
getView().getTabPanel().addBeforeSelectionHandler(new BeforeSelectionHandler<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onBeforeSelection(BeforeSelectionEvent<Integer> event)
            {
                showPopupupsForTab(event.getItem());
            }
        });
```

In showPopupupsForTab you can show the popups for this tab (you can handle this with a map or something) and hide the others...

Something like this.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about something like that too, but hoped that there was a diffrent or even native solution.

Comment: i believe nope... but, if you found something, let me know :)